# Timing synchronization

Tags: algorithm, lua, timing

I'm trying to masochistically sync note timings to align to this grid: (zoom in to see the grid properly)

[image]

(notice how 2 of the rows don't align right) but everything I try doesn't seem to work. My main issue is that this **must** be done in real-time, I can't preprocess it. (it's already slow enough as it is)

To explain the image:

The first row of the image is the max speed at which notes play. It's 20 NPS (notes per second). The second row doesn't align to the grid, it is 13.25 NPS. The 3rd 10 NPS. The 4th is 6.25 NPS. All the others are 20/n for n from 3 to 20.

If we call each section of the grid a "frame", and considering 20 NPS matches up with the frames, we have 20 FPS. The only thing I can do here is to choose in which frame to play a note. That is, for 20 NPS, I play a note on every frame, but for 10 NPS I skip 1 frame every note, and so on...

What I'm trying to do is come up with an algorithm that skips frames so that a 13.25 NPS song would still sound good even if I have to match/align notes to the 20 NPS/FPS grid.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

You can see everything I've already tried here: https://github.com/SoniEx2/NBSPlayer/commits/eef9ad465a1e337b17ad4e27e9a22d8a9dddfe4d/ats

Comment: added answer you may also want to google for (Up/Down/Re)Sampling methods ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked code would never work, as there is a [bug](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/22861-1710-sleep-sleeping-for-incorrect-amount-of-ticks/) with sleep() that makes it sleep too long. But here is a workaround:

Instead of calling sleep() directly, you should call it like so:

```lua
local function sleep_workaround(d)
    local t = d * 20
    for i=1,math.floor(t) do
        sleep(0.05) -- 0.05s sleeps don't trigger the bug
    end
end
```

This is due to faulty ComputerCraft code doing `x -= 0.05` each tick, which causes floating point errors, instead of converting the input to an integer and doing `x -= 1` each tick. As ComputerCraft uses Java, this is some simple Java code that shows the bug:

```java
for (double d : new double[]{0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0}) {
    int i;
    double in = d;
    for (i = 0; d > 0.0; i++, d -= 0.05) {}
    System.out.println(in + " " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I do not think that without sampling on higher rates  any change will do any good.**

- sound is tricky for example

  1. if you will add variable time skipping to match 13.25 nps in 20 nps grid

     - that will create skipping in almost every other note in 20 nps
     - but not all and that is noticeable in sound as glitches or miss tempo
     - due to manner of how we perciewe and decode sound by Brain.
  2. if you align 13.25nps to 10 nps instead

     - then of coarse you are out of sync in time anyway resp. out of wanted tempo

**So I see as the only way to use higher sampling rate**

- LCM least common multiply or high enough to lower the timing error so it is not noticeable
- for example use grid: 2000 nps + variable skipping that will create sync errors just up to 1ms
- and that is noticeable only by very good musical hearing people which aren't that many

**How to implement variable skipping**

- it is the same as drawing 2D line
- so use Bresenham,DDA,(sub)division or what ever
- just swap axises x=sampling rate grid, y=target rate grid
- for example something like this (in C++):

  ```
  int f0=200000,f1=1325,f2=2000,cnt1=f1,cnt2=f2; // rates are *100 to avoid use of floats
  for (ix=0;ix<???;ix++) sample[ix]=0;             // erase all samples before so you can add more then one sample in single pass later
  for (ix=0;ix<???;ix++)                             // loop to handle your samples ...
   {
   cnt1-=f1; if (cnt1<=0) { cnt1+=f0; sample[ix]+=???; /*/ here add samples for tempo 1 /*/ }
   cnt2-=f2; if (cnt2<=0) { cnt2+=f0; sample[ix]+=???; /*/ here add samples for tempo 2 /*/ }
   }
  ```
- of coarse I assume your notes have defined length so you need to set more samples per note then one so set samples `ix,ix+1,ix+2,...`
- as you can see you can add as many tempos as you need just have `cnt?,f?` variable for each of them
- you can play with the conditions use `(cnt?<0)` or use `framerates-1` to achieve different align/aliasing styles ...

Comment: Considering I'm limited to the system speed (the system I'm interacting with can only play at 20 "FPS") I can't use this. And considering preprocessing works and sounds good (altho I used an external program for it), I'm pretty sure this is possible.

Comment: @SoniEx2 in that case you can only use variable skipping to achieve timing but you can not avoid glitches at all, sad to hear/read that. the target device is some MIDI or FM stuff?

Comment: It's... actually Minecraft .-.